# Linux: command to lower window with focus

Tags: linux, xdotools

I'm looking for a command to lower a window with focus to the bottom of the stack of windows. I have a command to raise a focused window to the top which is:

```
xdotool getwindowfocus windowraise
```

...but I can't find one that moves the window to the bottom.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do, if your window manager has a key binding (eg `F3`) or mouse
button to lower a window, is use xdotool to find the window, move the mouse
into it, send the key sequence, and restore the mouse position.

```
wid=$(xdotool search --name 'Firefox')
xdotool windowactivate $wid
xdotool mousemove --window $wid 10 10 key F3 mousemove restore
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it doesn't, or I can't find it and what I'm actually trying to do is create a keybinding with the command. I've managed to do it for "raise window" which already is a good step forward. My distribution is KXStudio.